# Submitting multiple forms in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm not sure if i'm going about this completely the wrong way, but in my html template i have a for loop that i want to present multiple forms, and one submit button to submit the data from all forms:

```
 {% for i in Attribute_list %}
<form action="/Project/create/" method=post>{% csrf_token %}
{{ i }}:
<input type=text name={{ i }}><br>
<hr>
{% endfor %}
<input type=submit>
```

The problem with this is it only submits the last form.

The other problem i'm running into is getting the data back from the view.  Since i'm naming the form the variable "i", i don't know how to "get" this data in my views.py:

```
def create_config(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data_list = []
        for data in request.POST.getlist():
            data_list.append(data)
```

Comment: why don't You want to place all `input`s in one `form`?

Comment: How about using Django's formset via [modelformset_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) or just regular a regular [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/)

Comment: what is `Attribute_list`? and is absence of quotes in html missprint or You have forgotten about them?

Comment: oleg, can you give me an example of what you mean about all inputs in one form?

Answer (score 0):

can You check  this?

```
<form action="/Project/create/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for i in Attribute_list %}
       {{ i }}: <input type="text" name="{{ i }}"><br>
       <hr>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

As I understand without JS regardless how many forms You create only one `POST` request will be made.

In oyur example HTML is not valid so It can behave different ways in different browsers. But as soon as You have not closed `form` last one should be submitted.

As for second part

```
def create_config(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data_list = []
        for data in request.POST.getlist():
            data_list.append(data)
```

I think You should use your `Attribute_list`. Or You can just iterate over all `POST' variables obtained.

```
def create_config(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data_list = []
        for key in request.POST:
            data_list.append(request.POST[key]) # or .extend(request.POST.getlist(key)
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems like this should work, but it's only posting the first form's data.